# HtmlPolicyBuilder OWASP Sanitizer

Tags: html, owasp

Can someone explain why when I do:

```
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
                .allowElements("a")
                .toFactory();
        policy.sanitize("<a></a>");
```

I get empty sanitised content ?

I use owasp-java-html-sanitizer-20200713.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using: .allowWithoutAttributes("a") Resolved problem.

According to
https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer

> > Please note that the elements "a", "font", "img", "input" and "span" need >>to be explicitly whitelisted using the allowWithoutAttributes() method if >>you want them to be allowed through the filter when these elements do not >>include any attributes.